# TypeError: makesentence() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'c', 'd', 'e', and 'f'

Tags: python, list

My task is: *"Use reduce to concatenate all the countries and to produce this sentence: Estonia, Finland, Sweden, Denmark, Norway, and Iceland are north European countries"* by using list.

Here are the list and my code:

```
countries = ['Estonia', 'Finland', 'Sweden', 'Denmark', 'Norway', 'Iceland']
def makesentence(a,b,c,d,e,f):
    return a+","+ b +","+ c +","+ d +","+ e +", and"+ f +"are north European countries"

print(reduce(makesentence,countries))
```

But I'm getting `TypeError: makesentence() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'c', 'd', 'e', and 'f'`

If I write something like it works with no error:

```
countries = ['Estonia', 'Finland']
print(reduce(lambda a,b:a+","+b+","+"are north European countries",countries))
```

What is the problem? I'm really confused.

Comment: For reduce, the function needs to take two arguments regardless of how many items are in the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`reduce()` calls the function with two arguments: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce

But you `makesentence()` provides 6 - so `c`, `d`, `e` and `f` are not set.

It is not clear what you want to do.

If you already have a function which takes all the arguments, you can just call it, like:

```
# python2
print(apply(makesentence,countries))

# python3
print(makesentence(*countries))
```

You already wrote the version using `reduce()` in your question.

Comment: I'm learning python from https://github.com/Asabeneh/30-Days-Of-Python/blob/master/14_Day_Higher_order_functions/14_higher_order_functions.md#exercises-level-2

He asked to do as an exercise. I couldn't do it but I understand now. Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
def makesentence(countries):
    result = ""
    for i in range(len(countries) - 1):
        result += countries[i] + ", "
    result += "and" + countries[-1] + "are north European countries"
    return result
countries = ['Estonia', 'Finland', 'Sweden', 'Denmark', 'Norway', 'Iceland']
print(makesentence(countries))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need *reduce* for this. It's this simple:

```
countries = ['Estonia', 'Finland', 'Sweden', 'Denmark', 'Norway', 'Iceland']

def makesentence(c):
    return ', '.join(c[:-1]) + ' and ' + c[-1] + ' are north European countries'

print(makesentence(countries))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const countries = ['Finland', 'Sweden', 'Denmark', 'Norway', 'IceLand'];

const sentence = countries.reduce((acc, country, index) => {
  if (index === countries.length - 1) {
    return acc + 'and ' + country;
  } else {
    return acc + country + ', ';
  }
}, 'Estonia, ');

console.log(sentence + ' are north European countries.');
```

the reduce method creates an accumulation variable named "acc". Each country name is iterated through in the array, and a concatenation operation is performed. When the last country is reached, the word "and" is added, completing the sentence. As a result, the desired sentence is obtained:

"Estonia, Finland, Sweden, Denmark, Norway, and Iceland are north European countries."

Please note that the order of countries in the array will affect the resulting sentence, so you need to ensure the correct order to obtain the desired output.